# Is there a way to connect the neptune database graph visualization to a custom portal?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, graph, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

I want to create a website and send queries to neptune db. How do I go about embedding the graph that's generated as a result of that query to my website?

Comment: Are you referring to the visualization features of the Neptune notebooks (workbench) or just creating graph visuals in general?

Comment: I was referring to the workbench/sagemaker visualization feature but my end goal is to create graph visuals

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying - I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to take the visualization code from the Jupyter notebooks and embed it directly into a portal. However, all of the code has been made [available as open source](https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook) and you are welcome to see if any of it helps with your work.

Generally, when building an experience in a website, people often use open source or commercial JavaScript libraries. Examples are Vis.js, Cytoscape and many based on top of D3.js.